# not receiving conversationUpdate event for deleting a team. MS Bot Framework for Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When some one installs my bot in Team, I am receiving conversationUpdate event and I will store it in my db. But when the Team is deleted I am not receiving any conversationUpdate event. Is there anyway that I can know when a Team is deleted. So that I can ask user to reinstall the bot in his new Team account.

Comment: Bot doesn't send any event when team is deleted, you will get it when it is renamed please look at [handle bot events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications)

Comment: Additionally, when a **channel** is _deleted_. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#channel-deleted